# How to send a message or abort to an http error page if the web socket connection is not established?

Tags: python, websocket, bottle, gevent

The example below is taken from their documentation and modified slightly. Why doesn't it abort when the web socket connection is not established?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import json
from bottle import route, run, request, abort, Bottle ,static_file
from pymongo import Connection
from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all()
from time import sleep

app = Bottle()

@app.route('/websocket')
def handle_websocket():
    wsock = request.environ.get('wsgi.websocket')
    if not wsock:
        abort(400, 'Expected WebSocket request.')
    while True:
        try:
            message = wsock.receive()
            wsock.send("Your message was: %r" % message)
            sleep(3)
            wsock.send("Your message was: %r" % message)
        except WebSocketError:
            break

@app.route('/<filename:path>')
def send_html(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root='./', mimetype='text/html')


from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
from geventwebsocket import WebSocketHandler, WebSocketError

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 8080

server = WSGIServer((host, port), app,
                    handler_class=WebSocketHandler)
print("access @ http://%s:%s/websocket.html" % (host,port)
server.serve_forever()
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/websocket");
    ws.onopen = function() {
        ws.send("Hello, world");
    };
    ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
        alert(evt.data);
    };
  </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to send a message to the frontend when the connection is not established?

Answer (score 0):

Websockets are designed to not abort easily.  Either the backend code needs to break the connection or the websocket just waits for the socket to open and continues as normal as messages come through.

However nothing in your code indicates something is wrong or when a connection is made or broken, it just looks like it will immediately send "Hello, World" once a connection is made, and then receive it back twice spaced by 3 seconds.